# MonoTouch for iPhone: When is UITextField's ValueChanged event fired?

Tags: xamarin.ios, uitextfield

Can anybody tell me when this event is fired?

Comment: The event I was looking for when I wrongly tried this one first, was `EditingChanged`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This event handler is bound to the control events for the underlying UIControl implementation for the given control event called...UIControlEventValueChanged

According to the Apple docs this means it is called when: "A touch dragging or otherwise manipulating a control, causing it to emit a series of different values."

This may or may not be what you want to trigger off of, plan accordingly.

For the full list of events: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html